SLAM toolbox error - Robot jumps when returning to base ((0, 0) or map frame)
I built a robot watching and following instructions from this channel: Articulated Robotics - Build your own Robot and for a while everything seemed to be working rather well however, it seems now I've encountered an strange behaviour.SLAM error - Strange behaviour
Here's what I can tell you about the behaviour:

It happens when my robot returns to the map tf after moving around a bit.
Unless, the above condition is met the robot performs well. Even with nav2 stack and autonomous navigation.
I'm using the stack straight from what is shown in Articulated robotics.

I've been trying for 2 weeks to get this working. I'm out of my wits. Any and all help would be really appreciated. Thank you.
Here's the yaml controller files I am using:
controller.yaml:
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 30
    use_sim_time: false

    diff_cont:
      type: diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController

    joint_broad:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

diff_cont:
  ros__parameters:
    publish_rate: 50.0

    base_frame_id: base_link

    left_wheel_names: ['left_wheel_joint']
    right_wheel_names: ['right_wheel_joint']
    wheel_separation: 0.46
    wheel_radius: 0.090

    use_stamped_vel: false #this may make system robust but for now keep it false as we're ot publishing timestamed data
    enable_odom_tf: true # turn this on always. otherwise other nodes are gonna publish something instead of proper encoder values.
    #debug: true

mapper_params_online_async.yaml:
slam_toolbox:
  ros__parameters:
    # ...Everything else above is same as default...
    
    # ROS Parameters
    odom_frame: odom
    map_frame: map
    base_frame: base_footprint
    scan_topic: /scan
    use_map_saver: true
    mode: mapping #localization #mapping

    # ...Everything else below is same as default...

twist_mux.yaml:
twist_mux:
  ros__parameters:
    topics:
      navigation:
        topic   : cmd_vel
        timeout : 0.5
        priority: 10
      tracker:
        topic   : cmd_vel_tracker
        timeout : 0.5
        priority: 20
      joystick:
        topic   : cmd_vel_joy
        timeout : 0.5
        priority: 100

